# Filtering identical elements with different values in columns

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

How could I filter the following data frame in R:

```
NR <- c("AW1","AW1","AW2","AW3","AW3","AW4","AW4")

TYPE <- c("KA","MA","KA2","KA","KA","MA","KA")

df <- data.frame(NR,TYPE)
```

So I receive and create a new dataframe:

```
NR  TYPE    
AW1 KA
AW1 MA
AW4 MA
AW4 KA
```

So the general idea is to find the identical values in first column but only with different values in second column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the `base` package to get the desired data.frame:

```
df <- df[which(duplicated(df$NR) | duplicated(df$NR, fromLast=TRUE)), ]
df <- df[which(!duplicated(df$TYPE) | !duplicated(df$TYPE, fromLast=TRUE)), ]
df
## NR TYPE
## 1 AW1   KA
## 2 AW1   MA
## 6 AW4   MA
## 7 AW4   KA
```

Answer (score 2):

Using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
group_by(NR) %>% 
filter(n_distinct(TYPE)>1)
```